# Redux Store: inputing values into store based on dropdown

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a dropdown for a todo in react Native where a user can select the day for the todo task and they can select a time which is either `morning`, `afternoon`, `evening`. How would I create a Redux store band input data based on the value selected .

For example `Monday` in the `afternoon`. Then enter true on the appropriate time. What is the best way to check which day it is an automatically enter true on the time based on the drop down.I have tried something but It seems too long and I feel there is a better way

This is what I have done so far, it's too long and messy.

```
import { TODO } from '../actions/todo'

const initialState = {
    todo :[],
    dayAndTime: {
        'morning': [],
        'afternoon': [],
        'evening': []
    }
}
const TodoReducer = (state=initialState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case TODO:
            if(action.day === 'Monday'){
                if(action.time === 'morning')
                    return {...state, dayAndTime: dayAndTime.morning.concat(true)}
            }
    
        default: 
            return state
    }
}

export default TodoReducer
```

[image: This is the dropDown]